# XSLT 1.0 - sort and delete duplicates

Tags: xml, sorting, duplicates, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file and have to work with it as it is.
With my XSLT stylesheet I want to create a nice announcement for Microsoft Word.

For the headline I need to sort a part of the booking numbers, but there may not be duplicates.

This is the relevant part of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Announcement>
    <Data>
        <Name>Overview Complete</Name>
        <Date>20230516</Date>
    </Data>
    <Bookings>
        <Act>
            <No>1</No>
            <Room>03</Room>
            <Bookingnumber>Z 5 BER 1258/2023</Bookingnumber>
            <Name>Example</Name>
        </Act>
        <Act>
            <No>2</No>
            <Room>27</Room>
            <Bookingnumber>Z 16 BER 521/2023</Bookingnumber>
            <Name>Example</Name>
        </Act>
        <Act>
            <No>3</No>
            <Room>06</Room>
            <Bookingnumber>Z 8 BER 2054/2023</Bookingnumber>
            <Name>Example</Name>
        </Act>
        <Act>
            <No>4</No>
            <Room>18</Room>
            <Bookingnumber>Z 5 BER 788/2023</Bookingnumber>
            <Name>Example</Name>
        </Act>
        <Act>
            <No>5</No>
            <Room>26</Room>
            <Bookingnumber>Z 1 BER 28/2023</Bookingnumber>
            <Name>Example</Name>
        </Act>
    </Bookings>
</Announcement>
```

This is part of my XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>

<xslt:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xslt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml"
    xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">
     
    <xslt:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
        
    <xslt:template match="Announcement">    
        <w:wordDocument xml:space="preserve">
            <w:docPr>
                <w:view w:val="print"/>
                <w:zoom w:percent="130"/>
                <w:hideSpellingErrors w:val="on" />
                <w:hideGrammaticalErrors w:val="on" />
                <w:validateAgainstSchema w:val="off"/>
                <w:saveInvalidXML w:val="off"/>
                <w:ignoreMixedContent w:val="off"/>
                <w:doNotUnderlineInvalidXML w:val="on" />
                <w:removeWordSchemaOnSave w:val="on" />
                <w:useXSLTWhenSaving w:val="on" />
                <w:saveThroughXSLT w:val="on" />
                <w:showXMLTags w:val="off" />
                <w:alwaysShowPlaceholderText w:val="off"/>
                <w:attachedTemplate w:val="Normal.dotm"/>
            </w:docPr>
            <w:body>
                <w:sectPr>
                    <w:pgMar w:top="900" w:bottom="900" w:right="1417" w:left="1420" w:header="0" w:footer="0" w:gutter="0"/>
                    <w:pgSz w:h="16838" w:w="11906" />
                </w:sectPr>
                <w:p>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>Booking Groups: </w:t>
                        <xslt:call-template name="SortedHeadline"/><w:br/>
                        <w:t>for </w:t>
                        <w:t><xslt:value-of select="./Data/Date"/></w:t>                    
                    </w:r>  
                </w:p>
            </w:body>
        </w:wordDocument>
    </xslt:template>    
        
    <xslt:template name="SortedHeadline">
            <xslt:for-each select="//Bookings/Act/Bookingnumber">
                <xslt:sort select="substring-before((substring-after(., 'Z ')), ' ')" data-type="number"/>
                <w:t><xslt:value-of select="substring-before((substring-after(., 'Z ')), ' ')"/></w:t>
                <xslt:choose>
                    <xslt:when test="position()=last()">
                            <w:t>. </w:t>
                    </xslt:when>
                    <xslt:otherwise>
                            <w:t>., </w:t>
                    </xslt:otherwise>
                </xslt:choose>
            </xslt:for-each>
    </xslt:template>

</xslt:stylesheet>
```

My outcome:

```
1., 5., 5., 8., 16.
```

What I need:

```
1., 5., 8., 16.
```

As you can see I managed to get the bookingnumber part and I could sort it. But I can't get rid of duplicates. Does someone have an idea?

Thank you so much!

Comment: The preferred method for removing duplicates in XSLT 1.0 is Muenchian grouping - see: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html. Some processors also support the EXSLT `set:distinct()` extension function -- P.S. Please provide a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Comment: Thank you. I now provided a minimal reproducible example and will keep this in mind for future posts.

Comment: And do consider moving to XSLT 2.0. It makes this kind of task so much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve this by grouping using the XSLT/Muenchian grouping method:

```
<xslt:key name="myKey" match="Bookingnumber" use="substring-before((substring-after(., 'Z ')), ' ')"/>

<xslt:template match="Announcement">
  <w:wordDocument xml:space="preserve">
          <w:docPr>
              <w:view w:val="print"/>
              <w:zoom w:percent="130"/>
              <w:hideSpellingErrors w:val="on" />
              <w:hideGrammaticalErrors w:val="on" />
              <w:validateAgainstSchema w:val="off"/>
              <w:saveInvalidXML w:val="off"/>
              <w:ignoreMixedContent w:val="off"/>
              <w:doNotUnderlineInvalidXML w:val="on" />
              <w:removeWordSchemaOnSave w:val="on" />
              <w:useXSLTWhenSaving w:val="on" />
              <w:saveThroughXSLT w:val="on" />
              <w:showXMLTags w:val="off" />
              <w:alwaysShowPlaceholderText w:val="off"/>
              <w:attachedTemplate w:val="Normal.dotm"/>
          </w:docPr>
          <w:body>
              <w:sectPr>
                  <w:pgMar w:top="900" w:bottom="900" w:right="1417" w:left="1420" w:header="0" w:footer="0" w:gutter="0"/>
                  <w:pgSz w:h="16838" w:w="11906" />
              </w:sectPr>
              <w:p>
                  <w:r>
                      <w:t>Booking Groups: </w:t>
                      <xslt:call-template name="SortedHeadline"/><w:br/>
                      <w:t>for </w:t>
                      <w:t><xslt:value-of select="./Data/Date"/></w:t>                    
                  </w:r>  
              </w:p>
          </w:body>
      </w:wordDocument>
</xslt:template>

<xslt:template name="SortedHeadline">
  <xslt:for-each select="//Bookings/Act/Bookingnumber[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('myKey', substring-before((substring-after(., 'Z ')), ' '))[1])]">
    <xslt:sort select="substring-before((substring-after(., 'Z ')), ' ')" data-type="number"/>
    <w:t>
      <xslt:value-of select="substring-before((substring-after(., 'Z ')), ' ')"/>
    </w:t>
    <xslt:choose>
      <xslt:when test="position()=last()">
        <w:t>. </w:t>
      </xslt:when>
      <xslt:otherwise>
        <w:t>., </w:t>
      </xslt:otherwise>
    </xslt:choose>
  </xslt:for-each>
</xslt:template>
```

Comment: Oh wow. I am truly impressed and extremly grateful. Thank you so very much for your answer. It words perfectly. And I appreciate that you kept your answer in the style of my code so I could easily try it out. This is amazing!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you can apply Muenchian grouping to your problem. To avoid repeated extracting of the required part, we will be using a variable (which in XSLT 1.0 needs to be converted to a node-set before further processing).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="act-by-booknum" match="act" use="@booknum" />

<xsl:template match="/Announcement">
    <!-- extract the relevant part of Bookingnumber -->
    <xsl:variable name="acts">
        <xsl:for-each select="Bookings/Act">
            <act booknum="{substring-before((substring-after(Bookingnumber, 'Z ')), ' ')}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <output>
        <!-- apply Muenchian grouping to get only the first item in each group -->
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($acts)/act[generate-id() = generate-id(key('act-by-booknum', @booknum)[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="@booknum" data-type="number"/>
            <item>
                <xsl:value-of select="@booknum"/>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```